# Unable to fit table to Page by aligning left

Tags: tables, tabularx

This post is subsequent to [Table is cut off using Stargazer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367480/table-is-cut-off-using-stargazer). I have another problem of a cut off table. Except this time it does seem to be something to do with table width.

I have attempted to flesh out the code where previously I was using simple fragments producible by various packages in R Studio. The main point here is I've been trying to make a table fit the space better because it currently goes off page - it's inefficient party because it won't seem to go left.

I tried using 'flush left' because of what I saw in this clearly similar question here [making a table fit on a page by moving it left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33345/making-a-table-fit-on-a-page-by-moving-it-left) which doesn't seem to have done anything. Unfortunately you will find I have butchered the code a little. I fully intend to learn to use it self-sufficiently but right now am doing it on the fly.

[image: Cut off table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,caption,ragged2e}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\hsize=7.5\hsize}X}
\newlength\mylength
\settowidth\mylength{Multicultu} % width of 2nd col.
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
\caption{}  \label{} 
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l p{\mylength} LLLLL @{}}  
\toprule 
& Test & Trust & Demographics & Immigration & Economic Model & Issue     Satisfaction & Demographic No Country \\ 
\hline
1 & R2 & 0.016 & 0.2 & 0.086 & 0.007 & 0.021 & 0.027 \\ 
2 & Predicted & 83.20\% & 83.3\%\% & 83.40\% & 82.7\%\% & 83.20\% & 84.50\% \\ 
  3 & AUC Index & 0.585 & 0.79 & 0.701 & 0.559 & 0.603 & 0.61 \\ 
  4 & Sum of squared errors & 4861.786003 & 4773.002716 & 1847.897222 & 1249.544564 & 5009.179836 & 5310.168732 \\ 
  5 & Expected value$|$H0 & 4862.80413 & 4777.131906 & 1835.302972 & 1249.164639 & 5003.713449 & 5311.013662 \\ 
  6 & SD & 0.545436987 & 3.006760697 & 1.739686944 & 0.10557875 & 0.673923831 & 0.953354286 \\ 
  7 & Z & -1.866627646 & -1.373301832 & 7.239377177 & 3.598496041 & 8.111283371 & -0.886270167 \\ 
  8 & P & 0.061953604 & 0.169658533 & 4.51E-13 & 0.000320063 & 5.01E-16 & 0.375471961 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx} 
\end{flushleft}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\hsize=7.5\hsize}X}` what????????????

Comment: paragraph indent is zero in a table so the only effect of `flushleft` is to add additional vertical space.

Comment: the `L` definition makes every column 7.5 times as wide as tabularx calculated that the column needs to be, I'm wondering what is the intended behaviour?

Comment: your comprehensive answer on your question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options gives almost all what should OP consider in his table design, however from his MWE can be concluded that he has some basic problems (see *David Carlisle* comments and provided answers) with table settings which might be worth to leave question open :)

Answer (score 2):

The posted code produces

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
```

as it has 7 declared columns but 8 columns of data.

Adding an extra L to fix that then you get the warning

```
Package tabularx Warning: X Columns too narrow (table too wide)
(tabularx)                 on input line 26.
```

because

```
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\hsize=7.5\hsize}X}
```

forces at each iteration every column to be seven and a half times wider than the width calculated, so `tabularx` has no chance of ever converging to the requested table width.

Then delete the `!` from

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
```

which should only be used in exceptional circumstances.

then I added `dcolumn` to allow decimal aligned columns (you could instead use `siunitx`)

Then define a command for the headings,

then it sort of fits but it's still far too tight to be readable, you could use `\tiny` instead of `\footnotesize` but do you need to give so many decimal places?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,caption,ragged2e}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcommand\hd[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt} % default: 6pt
\caption{}  \label{} 

\begin{tabular}{@{}rp{2cm} *{6}{D..{1.9}}@{}}  
\toprule 
&
\hd{Test} &
\hd{Trust}&
\hd{Demo-\\graphics} &
\hd{Immi-\\gration}&
\hd{Economic\\Model}&
\hd{Issue\\Satisfaction}&
\hd{Demo-\\graphic\\No\\Country}\\ 
\hline
1 & R2 & 0.016 & 0.2 & 0.086 & 0.007 & 0.021 & 0.027 \\ 
2 & Predicted & 83.20\% & 83.3\%\% & 83.40\% & 82.7\%\% & 83.20\% & 84.50\% \\ 
  3 & AUC Index & 0.585 & 0.79 & 0.701 & 0.559 & 0.603 & 0.61 \\ 
  4 & Sum of\newline squared errors & 4861.786003 & 4773.002716 & 1847.897222 & 1249.544564 & 5009.179836 & 5310.168732 \\ 
  5 & Expected value$|$H0 & 4862.80413 & 4777.131906 & 1835.302972 & 1249.164639 & 5003.713449 & 5311.013662 \\ 
  6 & SD & 0.545436987 & 3.006760697 & 1.739686944 & 0.10557875 & 0.673923831 & 0.953354286 \\ 
  7 & Z & -1.866627646 & -1.373301832 & 7.239377177 & 3.598496041 & 8.111283371 & -0.886270167 \\ 
  8 & P & 0.061953604 & 0.169658533 & 4.51E-13 & 0.000320063 & 5.01E-16 & 0.375471961 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 

\end{table}


\end{document}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,caption,ragged2e}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcommand\hd[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt} % default: 6pt
\caption{}  \label{} 

\begin{tabular}{@{}rp{2cm} *{6}{D..{1.9}}@{}}  
\toprule 
&
\hd{Test} &
\hd{Trust}&
\hd{Demo-\\graphics} &
\hd{Immi-\\gration}&
\hd{Economic\\Model}&
\hd{Issue\\Satisfaction}&
\hd{Demo-\\graphic\\No\\Country}\\ 
\hline
1 & R2 & 0.016 & 0.2 & 0.086 & 0.007 & 0.021 & 0.027 \\ 
2 & Predicted & 83.20\% & 83.3\%\% & 83.40\% & 82.7\%\% & 83.20\% & 84.50\% \\ 
  3 & AUC Index & 0.585 & 0.79 & 0.701 & 0.559 & 0.603 & 0.61 \\ 
  4 & Sum of\newline squared errors & 4861.786003 & 4773.002716 & 1847.897222 & 1249.544564 & 5009.179836 & 5310.168732 \\ 
  5 & Expected value$|$H0 & 4862.80413 & 4777.131906 & 1835.302972 & 1249.164639 & 5003.713449 & 5311.013662 \\ 
  6 & SD & 0.545436987 & 3.006760697 & 1.739686944 & 0.10557875 & 0.673923831 & 0.953354286 \\ 
  7 & Z & -1.866627646 & -1.373301832 & 7.239377177 & 3.598496041 & 8.111283371 & -0.886270167 \\ 
  8 & P & 0.061953604 & 0.169658533 & 4.51E-13 & 0.000320063 & 5.01E-16 & 0.375471961 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Actually, you need a format of `D..{2.9}` to allow for the minus sign, but as noted above 9 decimal places seems excessive for a table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,caption,ragged2e}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcommand\hd[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt} % default: 6pt
\caption{}  \label{} 

\begin{tabular}{@{}r>{\raggedright}p{1.4cm} *{6}{D..{2.9}}@{}}  
\toprule 
&
\hd{Test} &
\hd{Trust}&
\hd{Demo-\\graphics} &
\hd{Immi-\\gration}&
\hd{Economic\\Model}&
\hd{Issue\\Satisfaction}&
\hd{Demo-\\graphic\\No\\Country}\\ 
\hline
1 & R2 & 0.016 & 0.2 & 0.086 & 0.007 & 0.021 & 0.027 \\ 
2 & Predicted & 83.20\% & 83.3\%\% & 83.40\% & 82.7\%\% & 83.20\% & 84.50\% \\ 
  3 & AUC\\ Index & 0.585 & 0.79 & 0.701 & 0.559 & 0.603 & 0.61 \\ 
  4 & Sum of\\ squared errors & 4861.786003 & 4773.002716 & 1847.897222 & 1249.544564 & 5009.179836 & 5310.168732 \\ 
  5 & Expec-\\ted value$|$H0 & 4862.80413 & 4777.131906 & 1835.302972 & 1249.164639 & 5003.713449 & 5311.013662 \\ 
  6 & SD & 0.545436987 & 3.006760697 & 1.739686944 & 0.10557875 & 0.673923831 & 0.953354286 \\ 
  7 & Z & -1.866627646 & -1.373301832 & 7.239377177 & 3.598496041 & 8.111283371 & -0.886270167 \\ 
  8 & P & 0.061953604 & 0.169658533 & 4.51E-13 & 0.000320063 & 5.01E-16 & 0.375471961 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for encouraging the OP to align the numbers on the decimal markers. In my answer, I make the suggestion, but I also suggest the OP round  the numbers -- I simply can see no justification for reporting 8 and 9 digits after the decimal marker.

Comment: yes as I comment in the text 9dp is almost certainly excessive for a table

Answer (score 2):

I test your table with following changes:

- font size: `\small`
- table environment `tabularx`
- use `S` columns' type for numbers
- reduce `\tabcolsep` to zero
- consider *David Carlisle* and *Mico* comments (in their answers)

The result is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,
            left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}%[!htbp]
    \small
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % default: 6pt
    \caption{}  
\label{tab:my problematic table}
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}   l @{\ } 
                                    L @{\quad}
                           *{6}{S[table-format=4.6,
                                  table-figures-exponent=1,
                                  table-align-text-post=false,
                                  table-align-exponent=false]}
                             @{} }
    \toprule
    & Test & Trust & {Demographics} & {Immigration} 
        & {\thead{Economic\\ Model}} & {\thead{Issue\\ Satisfaction}} 
            & {\thead{Demographic\\ No Country}} \\
    \midrule
 1 & R2         & 0.016         & 0.2           & 0.086         & 0.007         & 0.021         & 0.027       \\
 2 & Predicted  & 83.20\%       & 83.3\%\%      & 83.40\%       & 82.7\%\%      & 83.20\%       & 84.50\%     \\
 3 & AUC Index  & 0.585         & 0.79          & 0.701         & 0.559         & 0.603         & 0.61        \\
 4 & Sum of squared errors 
                & 4861.786003   & 4773.002716   & 1847.897222   & 1249.544564   & 5009.179836   & 5310.168732 \\
 5 & Expected value$|$H0 
                & 4862.80413    & 4777.131906   & 1835.302972   & 1249.164639   & 5003.713449   & 5311.013662 \\
 6 & SD         & 0.545436987   & 3.006760697   & 1.739686944   & 0.10557875    & 0.673923831   & 0.953354286 \\
 7 & Z          & -1.866627646  & -1.373301832  & 7.239377177   & 3.598496041   & 8.111283371   & -0.886270167\\
 8 & P          & 0.061953604   & 0.169658533   & 4.51e-13      & 0.000320063   & 5.01e-16      & 0.375471961 \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,caption,ragged2e,longtable}
    \captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\hsize=7.5\hsize}X}
    \newlength\mylength
    \settowidth\mylength{Multicultu} % width of 2nd col.
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htbp]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
    \caption{}  \label{} 
     \begin{flushleft}
     \begin{longtable}[H]{clcccccc}
      \toprule 
      & Test & Trust & Demographics & Immigration & Economic Model & Issue Satisfaction & Demographic No Country \\ 
     \midrule
     1 & R2 & 0.016 & 0.2 & 0.086 & 0.007 & 0.021 & 0.027 \\ 
     2 & Predicted & 83.20\% & 83.3\%\% & 83.40\% & 82.7\%\% & 83.20\% & 84.50\% \\ 
     3 & AUC Index & 0.585 & 0.79 & 0.701 & 0.559 & 0.603 & 0.61 \\ 
     4 & Sum of squared errors & 4861.786003 & 4773.002716 & 1847.897222 & 1249.544564 & 5009.179836 & 5310.168732 \\ 
      5 & Expected value$|$H0 & 4862.80413 & 4777.131906 & 1835.302972 & 1249.164639 & 5003.713449 & 5311.013662 \\ 
      6 & SD & 0.545436987 & 3.006760697 & 1.739686944 & 0.10557875 & 0.673923831 & 0.953354286 \\ 
      7 & Z & -1.866627646 & -1.373301832 & 7.239377177 & 3.598496041 & 8.111283371 & -0.886270167 \\ 
      8 & P & 0.061953604 & 0.169658533 & 4.51E-13 & 0.000320063 & 5.01E-16 & 0.375471961 \\ 
     \bottomrule
     \end{longtable} 
     \end{flushleft}
     \end{table}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: longtable does not have an `[H]` option and should never be inside `flushleft` or `table` environments.

Comment: thanking you for correcting me , longtable has only c, r and l option. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: I know, I wrote it.

Comment: you could edit the answer to fix the errors also you changed the page size which is usually not an option to make a table fit into a document.

Answer (score 1):

Your table is experiencing a number of serious issues.

- What, pray tell, are you doing showing 8 or 9 digits after the decimal marker? Three digits should be more than enough. Either perform the rounding manually or load the `siunitx` package and let the package's `S` column type perform the rounding for you.
- And what is `>{\hsize=7.5\hsize}X` even supposed to mean? I can see no reason for not making the six (not five) data columns equally wide.
- You have several instances of `\%\%` -- it looks very untidy.
- Using a `flushleft` environment is not needed. Don't use it.

In the following table, note that the main column type of the six data columns is `S`, to align the numbers on their respective decimal markers and to round the numbers, as discussed above. The six header cells, though, are wrapped in `\mC` directives to assure that the overall width of the `tabularx` environment is `\textwidth`. Observe how the text in some (but not all) of the text in the headers occupies two lines.

[image]